# app crash with Memory Pressure,how can I solve it

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, crash, memory-pressure

My iOS games debug it in device,would crash in every 5 minutes.In my games,some object are retain,and some are autorelease.I know my games have memory leaks,but I try to fix it in my best.What should I do next?

I tried to use Insturment Leaks to trace where leak,and tried device debug log,too.But nothing help.

Thx a lot.

PS:forget my fundamental English.

Comment: Use ARC. It will manage memory a lot better than you can do by retain and autorelease.

Comment: @matt I think in this case,I should not use ARC.Any other way to solve it?

Comment: Of course there is another way. You could learn to manage memory correctly yourself. But you clearly have not managed that. Which is going to be easier for you, learn something you clearly have not succeeded in learning, or choose Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC?

Comment: Also you clearly (from your other comments) have no idea what ARC even is. Like a child who refuses to taste an unfamiliar food, you just reject it without thinking. Vote to close on that basis.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the questioner gives no information whatever about the problem and refuses to accept advice.

Comment: Sorry for that.Of course,I am a rookie in OC.I just learn it 1 week by myself.So,I can't manage this big project and I have no idea for that problem. :-(

Comment: But anyway,thanks your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use automatic reference counting (ARC), it will automatically handle the memory better than what you are doing

Comment: but if I use ARC,everythings are out of my control.for example,if I want that image display in sometime,but I don't know what time exactly.In this situation,should I have to use ARC?

Comment: ARC will automatically remove the bad memory which is not using in the  project, but it cannot delete the objects, so whenever you need that image which you want, you can access that image.

Comment: is that mean after I use ARC,I could access my Image anytime?Because some image I don't use at present don't mean I don't use it later.Or,if I use ARC,everytime I want to use that Image,I should alloc it with "autorelease"?not "retain"?

Comment: when you use ARC, you dont have to use autorelease, it will release the bad memory by itself

Comment: Yeah,I get it.So,you suggest me to transfer my project to ARC mode?I think you would take a lot of time,because my project is very huge,I am a part of the project.The amount of code I think is over 250,000 lines.

Comment: yeah. It takes a lot of time, but it will help you..and this is the only solution. Kindly accept the answer